# How to use LINQ to populate a object with a List<int> and a String?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6.3 and LINQ to query from a table and populate the DTO object below:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<int> Number { get; set; }

   public MyClass()
   {
       Number = new List<int>();
   }
}
```

In this particular table (legacy project), the *Name* can have multiple *Numbers*, hence my need to use it as a list.

The table looks like this:

```
Name      Number
abc       15371
abc       15079
abc       15371
abc       30392
xyz       30373
xyz       13141
```

My code, for now, is as follow:

```
List<MyObjetct> myObject = new List<MyObjetct>();

myObject = contex.TableName.Where(x => listOfNames.Contains(x.Name))
                           .Select( y => new MyObject() 
                           {
                              name = y.name
                              number = *populate the list of numbers*
                           });
```

I was hoping to populate a list of MyObjects with names and a list o numbers.

Comment: How are the numbers structured in the name field?  We can't see your data.

Comment: @Amy edited the question with the table

Comment: you want to group by name and get corresponding numbers as list?

Comment: I see. The way your question is phrased made it sound like the name field *contains* numbers.

Comment: @Selvin Yes, thats a better way of explaning it.

Comment: Then you should use something like `...GroupBy(x=>x.Key).Select(x=>new { x.Key, list = x.Select(y=>y.num).ToList()})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
myObject = contex.TableName.GroupBy(t => t.Name)
.Where(g => listOfNames.Contains(g.Key))
.Select(g => new MyObject()
{
    name = g.Key,
    number = g.Select(n => n.Number).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Output:

> Name / Numbers
>
> abc / 15371,15079,15371,30392
>
> xyz / 30373,13141

I noticed your data sample has repeat name/number combinations. Not sure if it's just a typo or if you need to account for that.

Comment: Shoudn't the `ToList` be with `number = g.Select(n => n.Number).ToList()`

Comment: As @Rakesh said, `ToList()` needs to be after `number = g.Select(n => n.Number).ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks both of you, it worked as expected. I only added a `Distinct()` after `number = g.Select(n => n.Number).Distinct().ToList()` to filter even more the results.

Comment: @Rakesh the data sample is correct. Using `Distinct()` solved the issue.

Comment: @Rakesh: You are correct. It should use `ToList`. I usually code against `IEnumerable` interfaces, hence the issue. I'll update the code but I would recommend the OP uses `IEnumerable<T>` instead.